# Segmentation fault when deleting linked list

Tags: c, list, pointers

I am trying to delete all the nodes on a linked list but I am getting a segmentation fault.

I had code that was working initially but I was only deleting the first node in the list, I want to delete all the nodes and delete all the pointers redundant pointers.

Also if some of you guys could check the function I am using to create the linked list and give me some feedback on whether you think it is ok or where some improvements could be made, I would appreciate it.

Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MEMORY_SIZE (15)


typedef struct link {
    double coeff;
    int pow;
    struct link * next;
} poly;

poly *polyArray[MEMORY_SIZE];// array of 15 polynomials to play with

// /** The function prototypes */
void createPoly(poly **);                   
void deletePoly(poly *);                    

/**
 * The main function
 */
int main(void) {

    printf("\n\n\t***************************************************");
/*  printf("\n\tDemonstrating Polynomial Creation");
    printf("\n\t***************************************************");*/      
        printf("\n\t1st polynomial\t");
        createPoly(&polyArray[0]);
        showPoly(polyArray[0]);
    srand(time(NULL));
//      printf("\n\n\tCreating and storing the 2nd polynomial\n");
//  createPoly(&polyArray[1]);
//  showPoly(polyArray[1]);



    showPoly(polyArray[0]); 
    printf("\n\t***************************************************");
    printf("\n\tProgram has Ended, Deleting all polynomials");
    printf("\n\t***************************************************"); 

        int count;
        for(count = 0; count < MEMORY_SIZE; count++)
    {
      deletePoly(polyArray[count]);
    }


    printf("\n\n"); 

    showPoly(polyArray[0]); 
  return 0;
}//end main function


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void createPoly(poly **node) {

    poly *tempnode; //To hold the temporary last address
    tempnode = (poly*)malloc( sizeof(poly) ); //create the first node
    *node = tempnode; //Store the head address to the reference variable

    int flag = 1 + rand()%3;; // A flag to control the number of terms
    int counter;

    for( counter = 0; counter <= flag; counter++ )
    {
          tempnode->pow = ( flag-counter );
      tempnode->coeff = ( (double)(rand()%20) )/( (double)(1 + rand()%20) );

      if( (counter < flag) && (counter >= 0)  )
        {
           tempnode->next = (poly*)malloc( sizeof(poly) ); //Grow the list
        }
      else if ( counter == flag )
        {
          tempnode->next = NULL;
        }

      tempnode = tempnode->next;
    }

}

void deletePoly(poly *node) {

  poly *temp;

  if( node->next == NULL ) 
    {
      free( node );
      node = NULL;
    }
  else
    {
      while( node->next != NULL )
    {
      temp = node->next;
      free( node );
      node = temp;
    }//end while
      node = NULL;
    }//end 'if/else'

}//end function 'deletePoly'
```

Comment: the bug is in `deletePoly`

Comment: Ok thanks, I am assuming it is inside the while loop in the poly, am I correct?

Comment: You're not checking for `if (!node)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, the `main` function is creating only the first polynomial (`poly[0]`), but you are trying to delete them all (the loop in the main function goes up to `MEMORY_SIZE`).

You should also initialize all your pointers to NULL before beginning the program (this is an important feature in C programs) and change the deletePoly this way:

```
void deletePoly(poly *node) {    
  poly *temp;      
  while( node != NULL ) {
      temp = node->next;
      free( node );
      node = temp;
  }//end while
  node = NULL;      

}//end function 'deletePoly'
```

Comment: Well yes, the array of pointers 'polyArray' can have 15 elements. And I want to point to the first polynomial (i.e. linked list) through index[0] of the array. The loop in main which goes up to MEMORY_SIZE obviously is not needed in this instance as I am only dealing with the element in polyArray[0] and could have done this explicitly but later I will be filling up this array and I want a way to clear it at the end out the program. I will change the code and try to run it, thanks.

Comment: Yes, but you did not initialize the variables and did not use elements 1 through 14. Try debugging your program and I am pretty sure the error will be caused when ddeletePoly is called in the loop when count=1 in the main function (sorry - no debuggers in this computer. I am doing things in my head)

Comment: Just don't forget the initialization part: for(count = 0; count < MEMORY_SIZE; count++) {poly[count]=NULL;} before everything starts.

Comment: Thanks guys, I got rid of the segmentation fault. I changed the code for deletePoly to the version rlinden posted above and I took the advice and initialise all the pointers in the array to NULL at the beginning.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Never forget to initialize. In C, this is a major cause for errors (I fell into this trap about a million times).

Comment: It is actually not deleting the list at polyArray[0] but I will play around with it and see what happens, If anyone has any advice on how I could improve this please feel free to comment. Thanks

Comment: I think that you should pass a **node and not *node. Once again - sorry but no debuggers in this computer.

Comment: Thanks but that changing the parameter of deletePoly to **node instead of *node did not work as the program would not compile. No matter I genuinely appreciate the help. Thanks